# How to write sql statements based on an inventory Database displaying revenue and sales data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Customer (
   Id                   int                  identity,
   FirstName            nvarchar(40)         not null,
   LastName             nvarchar(40)         not null,
   City                 nvarchar(40)         null,
   Country              nvarchar(40)         null,
   Phone                nvarchar(20)         null,
   constraint PK_CUSTOMER primary key (Id)

create table "Order" (
   Id                   int                  identity,
   OrderDate            datetime             not null default getdate(),
   OrderNumber          nvarchar(10)         null,
   CustomerId           int                  not null,
   TotalAmount          decimal(12,2)        null default 0,
   constraint PK_ORDER primary key (Id)
)

create table OrderItem (
   Id                   int                  identity,
   OrderId              int                  not null,
   ProductId            int                  not null,
   UnitPrice            decimal(12,2)        not null default 0,
   Quantity             int                  not null default 1,
   constraint PK_ORDERITEM primary key (Id)

create table Product (
   Id                   int                  identity,
   ProductName          nvarchar(50)         not null,
   SupplierId           int                  not null,
   UnitPrice            decimal(12,2)        null default 0,
   Package              nvarchar(30)         null,
   IsDiscontinued       bit                  not null default 0,
   constraint PK_PRODUCT primary key (Id)

create table Supplier (
   Id                   int                  identity,
   CompanyName          nvarchar(40)         not null,
   ContactName          nvarchar(50)         null,
   ContactTitle         nvarchar(40)         null,
   City                 nvarchar(40)         null,
   Country              nvarchar(40)         null,
   Phone                nvarchar(30)         null,
   Fax                  nvarchar(30)         null,
   constraint PK_SUPPLIER primary key (Id)
)

INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Country],[Phone])VALUES(6,'Hanna','Moos','Mannheim','Germany','0621-08460')
INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Country],[Phone])VALUES(7,'Frédérique','Citeaux','Strasbourg','France','88.60.15.31')
INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Country],[Phone])VALUES(8,'Martín','Sommer','Madrid','Spain','(91) 555 22 82')

INSERT INTO [Supplier] ([Id],[CompanyName],[ContactName],[City],[Country],[Phone],[Fax])VALUES(4,'Tokyo Traders','Yoshi Nagase','Tokyo','Japan','(03) 3555-5011',NULL)
INSERT INTO [Supplier] ([Id],[CompanyName],[ContactName],[City],[Country],[Phone],[Fax])VALUES(5,'Cooperativa de Quesos ''Las Cabras''','Antonio del Valle Saavedra','Oviedo','Spain','(98) 598 76 54',NULL)
INSERT INTO [Supplier] ([Id],[CompanyName],[ContactName],[City],[Country],[Phone],[Fax])VALUES(6,'Mayumi''s','Mayumi Ohno','Osaka','Japan','(06) 431-7877',NULL)

INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id],[ProductName],[SupplierId],[UnitPrice],[Package],[IsDiscontinued])VALUES(4,'Chef Anton''s Cajun Seasoning',2,22.00,'48 - 6 oz jars',0)
INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id],[ProductName],[SupplierId],[UnitPrice],[Package],[IsDiscontinued])VALUES(5,'Chef Anton''s Gumbo Mix',2,21.35,'36 boxes',1)
INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id],[ProductName],[SupplierId],[UnitPrice],[Package],[IsDiscontinued])VALUES(6,'Grandma''s Boysenberry Spread',3,25.00,'12 - 8 oz jars',0)

INSERT INTO [Order] ([Id],[OrderDate],[CustomerId],[TotalAmount],[OrderNumber])VALUES(5,'Jul  9 2012 12:00:00:000AM',76,3730.00,'542382')
INSERT INTO [Order] ([Id],[OrderDate],[CustomerId],[TotalAmount],[OrderNumber])VALUES(6,'Jul 10 2012 12:00:00:000AM',34,1444.80,'542383')
INSERT INTO [Order] ([Id],[OrderDate],[CustomerId],[TotalAmount],[OrderNumber])VALUES(7,'Jul 11 2012 12:00:00:000AM',14,625.20,'542384')
INSERT INTO [Order] ([Id],[OrderDate],[CustomerId],[TotalAmount],[OrderNumber])VALUES(8,'Jul 12 2012 12:00:00:000AM',68,2490.50,'542385')

INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(4,2,14,18.60,9)
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(5,2,51,42.40,40)
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(6,3,41,7.70,10)
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(7,3,51,42.40,35)
INSERT INTO [OrderItem] ([Id],[OrderId],[ProductId],[UnitPrice],[Quantity])VALUES(8,3,65,16.80,15)
```

I need assistance in answering the following:

a.How many products are currently being sourced from each supplier? Note: 1 =
Discontinued.

b. What is the number of orders and revenue per month for 2012, 2013 and 2014? Results should be in one table.

c. What are the total sales and number of orders per customer?

Comment: np..I have the code in that format already in SQL...

Comment: a. Select CompanyName,Count(Product.Id) as TotalProducts
    From Supplier,Product
    where IsDiscontinued = 0
     Group by CompanyName

b.Select count(OrderNumber) as Total_Orders, sum(TotalAmount) as Revenue, month(OrderDate) as Month ,year(OrderDate) as Year
From [Order]
Group by month(OrderDate), year(OrderDate)

c. Select count(OrderNumber) as Total_Orders, sum(TotalAmount) as TotalSales, CustomerId
From [Order]
Group by CustomerId
Order by CustomerID ASC;